# How to notify client applications from a service on a Windows system with WinAPI and C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, ipc

I was wondering, what is the best way to do the following using C++/WinAPIs on a Windows system?

I have a local service application along with running client applications (that run on each logged on user session account.) The service application needs to notify all client applications to perform a one time operation (say, read data from registry and process it.) How do you implement this mechanism of notifying all client apps of a one-time event?

Answer (score 1):

Service could send a broadcast windows message for which all client apps would listen. Of course, client apps need to have a message loop. Have you looked at [SendNotifyMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I didn't think about. My only concern is, would it work across sessions? For instance, if the client app is running in a logged on session 1 and session 2, will both copies receive this message?

Comment: I actually did it this way -- a client app creates a global named event by appending its session ID to its name. One can get it from ProcessIdToSessionId API. A client then can waits on it to be signaled. Then to notify clients the service opens each of those events and signals them individually. The service can get session IDs of all logged on users by calling WTSEnumerateSessions. This is a little bit more complicated but seems to work without the need for message loops.

Comment: Just learned it by trying it out, SendNotifyMessage will NOT work like it was suggested above. My method described in the post above, will ...

Comment: It was not too obvious that apps would run under different login sessions. That's probably why SendNotifyMessage is not working for you. Glad to hear you eventually solved your problem though.

Comment: It would not work even if it's just one logged on user session. This was introduced since Windows Vista -- it's called "Session isolation" which means that one will not be able to send a message to a user process from a system service.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a particular name that all the apps agree on. Then reset it after a period of time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you see, the issue is how to do it only once? If I create a manual reset event each client app will check if such event is set by calling WaitForSingleObject and continue doing so indefinitely. If, on the other hand, I create an autoreset event, only one client app will get notified, but what about the rest?